# PWA works on localhost, does not work on Vercel

Tags: progressive-web-apps, vite, vercel

I am using React + TypeScript + Vite

I have been browsing the net for this issue, but it seems there is nobody on this holy planet to have ever created a PWA and have deployed it on Vercel. Otherwise there would be a note on Vercel docs about PWA or the same thread on this website. I suppose, it is either the problem with Vercel building my app not properly or it's me being uneducated for this.

### Localhost

[pwa working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t76e0.png)
[pwa working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLPaq.png)

### Deployed on Vercel

[pwa not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpxFI.png)

### PWA code

**App.tsx** *(registering a service worker)*

```js
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
  if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
    await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.ts')
    console.log('service worker registered successfully')
  }
})
```

**service-worker.ts**

```js
/// <reference path="node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts" />

const serviceWorker = self as unknown as ServiceWorkerGlobalScope

const cacheName = 'app-cache'
const cacheVersion = 0
const cacheFullName = `${cacheName}-${cacheVersion}`

serviceWorker.addEventListener('install', async e => {
  const cache = await caches.open(cacheFullName)
  await cache.addAll([
    '/index.html',
    '/src/index.scss',
    '/src/assets/images/favicon.png',
    '/src/assets/images/logo-color.png',
    '/src/assets/images/logo-solid.png',
  ])
});

serviceWorker.addEventListener('activate', async e => {
  const cachesNames = await caches.keys()
  cachesNames.map(async cacheName => cacheName !== cacheFullName && await caches.delete(cacheName))
})

serviceWorker.addEventListener('fetch', async e => {
  e.respondWith(caches.match(e.request).then(res => res ? res : fetch(e.request)))
})
```

**manifest.json**

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/web-manifest",
  "name": "Shtosh",
  "short_name": "Shtosh",
  "background_color": "#030712",
  "lang": "en",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#030712",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "start_url": ".",
  "shortcuts": [
    {
      "url": ".",
      "name": "Созданные",
      "description": "Опросы, созданные вами",
      "icons": [
        {
          "src": "/src/assets/images/logo.svg",
          "sizes": "any",
          "type": "image/svg+xml",
          "purpose": "any"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "description": "Создавайте и проходите опросы быстро и удобно",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/src/assets/images/logo.svg",
      "sizes": "any",
      "type": "image/svg+xml",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "/src/assets/images/logo-color.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "/src/assets/images/logo-color.png",
      "sizes": "any",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable"
    }
  ]
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="Проходите, создавайте опросы и делитесь ими с сообществом и со своими знакомыми."/>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#030712">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/src/assets/images/favicon.png"/>
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/src/assets/images/logo-color.png">
    <title>ШТОШ</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**vercel.json**

```json
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "destination": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```

**vite.config.ts**

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), svgr()],
  build: {
    target: 'esnext'
  },
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 3000
  }, 
  resolve: {
    alias: [{find: '@', replacement: '/src'}]
  }
})
```